# Double Increasing Series relation explanation

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was solving this question: https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/double-increasing-series/

Basically the question is:

> Given two integers A and B.
> Find the number of sequences of length B, such that every element of this sequence is an positive integer and is less than of equal to A, also every previous element in the sequence is less than or equal to half of the next element.

This is a dynamic programming problem.
Its solution on the site is given as: `DP (i, j) = DP (i-1, j) + DP (floor(i/2), j-1)`.

Can anyone explain how this result came? I searched online but couldn't find any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The formula given is `DP[i][j] = DP[i-1][j] + DP[i/2][j-1]`, where

- `i` is the maximum value of sequence (surely the last value of sequence).
- `j` is the length of the sequence.
- `DP[i][j]` is the total number of sequences ending at a integer `<= i` and of length `j`.

Now try to understand this formula by an example.

Assume you want to find the number of sequences ending at an integer `<= 50` and length 5, means `DP[50][5]`. Now give it a thought that sequences which were ending at an integer `<= 49` and length 5 (`DP[49][5]`), can also be counted in sequences ending at an integer `<= 50` and length 5 (`DP[50][5]`).

Now we will consider those sequences which are ending strictly at integer 50. Now the sequences which were ending at an integer `<= 25` (`50 / 2`) and of length 4 (`5 - 1`), means `DP[25][4]`. By appending the 50 at the end of those sequences we can make new sequences ending at 50 and of length 5. So by adding `DP[49][5]` and `DP[25][4]`, we can get `DP[50][5]`.